# Cant publish to Azure from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to publish an application to Azure and am being shown an error stating

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred.
>
> Additional information: Windows Azure Management certificate not found.  Thumbprint: 
>        Parameter Name: certificateThumbprint

I have had no luck finding an answer and was hoping someone here might be able to tell me whats going on??

Answer (score 0):

Very often, company proxy servers strip out the certificate that Visual Studio needs to access Azure.

If this is the case for you, you need to bypass the proxy server.

There is also a bug in VS2013 that [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/11/web-deploy-3-6-beta-released/) fixes for proxy server issues.